# What is wrong with this excerpt?

Tags: c

I'm reading the book The Practice of Programming by Brian W.Kernighan, and I don't quite understand exercise 1-5 in it.

> Exercise 1-5. What is wrong with this excerpt?

```
int read(int *ip) {
    scanf("%d", ip);
    return *ip;
}
    ...
insert(&graph[vert], read(&val), read(&ch));
```

Answer (score 16):

```
insert(&graph[vert], read(&val), read(&ch));
```

It's unspecified whether `read(&val)` is called first, or `read(&ch)` is called first, so you never know which one you are inputting.